# Kill Process When Specific Process is Running

Tags: process, kill

I'm looking to make a script that would kill a specific running processer i'm going to call A.exe, and once certain process started, i'm going to call B.exe, it will automatically kill A.exe, and once B.exe stopped running, it will reopen process A.exe

I hope its clear, thanks in advance!

I'm still not sure which script I would use, my codding skills very limited, I hope someone would let me know if this is possible.